# How does Russian law handle real estate on the conquered territories?

Tags: real-estate, russia

Now that Russia has conquered a lot of Ukrainian territory, there is the problem about the ownership of the real estates there.

Normally, in countries, there should be a governmental office to register the ownerships of the real estates in their territory. This must exist in Ukraine and very likely it exists also in Russia. However, it is very unlikely that the Russian office could simply get the database from the Ukrainian side.

Beside that, a large part of the population flees or being evacuated, sometimes forcibly, before the front arrives to them. They must leave their real estates back. After the front, if their homes are repairable, they would somehow need to go back and there prove that they are the owners. Here is yet another problem, and that is that currently no one can step over the front without an overwhelming military supremacy, what a civilian unlikely has. Beside that, it would be also probably at least criminal offense on the Ukrainian law.

The people waiting the Russians and surviving the siege, have again the problem, that after the front goes over them, they can not access Ukraine any more. The normal order of the things would be that they visit the Ukrainian governmental office to get document about the real estate ownership, they go with these documents to the Russians and they get the Russian papers for that. Obviously it is impossible, among numerous other reasons, because communicating with the enemy is normally criminal offense on both sides.

So, there is the city in ruins, with civilians in the cellar. There are no documents. What says the Russian law, how is being decided, who owns which home?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is politically too loaded and untested. It is bound to attract unwanted partisan attention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Russian law has no jurisdiction in Ukraine. None. Zilch. Not even in occupied territory.

Comment: @WeatherVane The conquered territories are in Russian jurisdiction on the Russian law.